# Sending audio file into server

Tags: json, rest, audio, ftp, base64

I'm little confused about sending audio files from my client app (max. 10 sec of audio) into my server. The question is - which of the following options is the best?

- From the client side save audio file into byte array and then convert it into Base64. After that send it in json request. On the server side, handle request in a Rest Api, decode Base64 and save it on the server. I was also wondering about making hash function of the audio file from the client side and send it also with the response and from the api compare these two hashes for integrity purposes (Missing packets or something).
- Send an audio file as multipart form-data in json response and handle it in my Rest Api.
- Simply saving file using FTP into my server.

Which option is the best? Or do you have any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the first bullet point you made, If you're sending files from the client to the server, that's a request from the client to the server (a request to store/upload an audio clip).

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right :).

Comment: There's some good info here, the suggestion is to use FTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467199/sending-a-large-file-from-a-client-to-a-server-is-my-logic-correct?rq=1